# Avoid duplicate entry constraint violation with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, unique

I have a mySQL table for user devices with a column `device_id`, which has a `UNIQUE` constraint assigned to.

In my Laravel application, my `APIController` class provides an API to add new devices to the table. The method looks like this:

```
public function postDevice(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    if(!$request->has('device_id'))
        return response()->json(['error' => 'You need to provide a unique device identifier "device_id".'], 460);

    $device_id = $request->input('device_id');

    $device = UserDevice::where('device_id', $device_id)->first();

    if($device) {
        // update device properties with transmitted data
        $device->fill($request->all());

        // make sure this device belongs to our user
        $device->user()->associate($user);

        $device->save();
    } else {
        // create new device for our user
        $user->devices()->create($request->all());
    }

    return response()->json(['status'=>'success']);
}
```

I thought that my condition would make sure that the uniqueness constraint cannot be violated through this API. But somehow I regularly get errors like this:

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'C02P69YWG3QC' for key 'user_devices_device_id_unique' (SQL: insert into 'user_devices' ('device_id', 'mac_model', 'mail_version', 'mailbutler_version', 'osx_version', 'user_id', 'updated_at', 'created_at') values (C02P69YWG3QC, MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013), 10.0 (3225), 6439, 10.12.0, 13400, 2016-09-13 12:17:56, 2016-09-13 12:17:56))
```

Do you have any idea how the constraint can be violated with the code shown above?
Is there a better coding paradigm to avoid such errors?

BTW: I am running this application with potentially multiple instances working on the same DB. Could there be a race condition involved?

Comment: Out of curiousity, what is the primary key on that table?

Comment: How is the device id generated?

Comment: The problem may arise from double-posting the same data. In that case you may need to obtain a write lock on the table before executing `$device = UserDevice::where('device_id', $device_id)->first();`

Comment: The primary key is `id` INT(11) for that table.

Comment: If the same data is posted twice, shouldn't the query return a result then?

Comment: Are you try  use `update` instead of `fill`?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use Validation?

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'device_id' => 'bail|required|unique:user_devices',
]);
```

Comment: Because this would reject a request with an already existing device ID, right? Instead I would like to update the existing row with potentially new data.